# Android Retrofit - send dynamic number of POST parameters

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

I need to send a dynamic number of POST parameter values to an endpoint (there could be 1 or there could be 50).  All of them will have the same key value.

Is this possible?  I can't seem to figure out how to create a RequestBody that encompasses something like this, even when I try to construct it in plain text.

I have the list of strings prepared for it, but I just don't know how to create this kind of thing.  The endpoint works in PostMan when I input a lot of post form parameters with the same key value, so the endpoint is setup properly for it.  I'm just not sure if Retrofit supports this kind of thing, and I cannot seem to find any info around it.

I'm currently working with Java instead of Kotlin.  Thoughts?

Comment: check out this page: https://square.github.io/retrofit/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also pass multiple field parameter to your request like this:

```java
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/oauth/access_token")
Call<YourResponseObject> sendData(
    @FieldMap Map<String, String> params
);
```

The map can take variable number of args.

So you can pass data like:

```java
/*
map = { "field1_key"="value1", "field2_key"="value2", "field3_key"="value3", ...}
*/
retrofit().create(YourInterface.class).sendData(mapOfFields)
```

**p.s:** `retrofit()` is a method that returns a `Retrofit` instance to work with.

Comment: Thank you!  I didn't realize you could do that and pass a map like that.

Comment: Looks like a Map does not allow multiple duplicate keys.  In my case I need them to be the same.  Is there a workaround for that?

Comment: Well, it doesn't make sense to pass a key with multiple values. You may want to send a nested map. In other words, your key (that wants to be duplicated) will have all values as a map or a list of values. `{key=value, key2={key21=val, key22=val2}}` or `{key1=value, key2=[value1,value2,...]`. For that you will need `Map<String, Object>` or `Map<String, Any>` in kotlin.

Comment: Thanks, yep you're right that it doesn't really make sense.  Luckily I was able to get the server team to make the change to allow incrementing numbers for the keys, so things are working now.  Thank you again!